# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'linkbacks' in 'field list'") - F() in django

Tags: python, django

I have the code:

```
Virality.objects.update(
    factor=F('shares')/F('linkbacks')*F('linkbacks_old')/F('shares_old'),
    linkbacks_old=F('linkbacks'), linkbacks=0
)
```

and all fields are migrated in db, they exist!

but while running the update above, I am getting:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'linkbacks' in 'field list'")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the model!

Comment: @KlausD. what you see are all fields of this model. nothing else